# syslinux pxe boot windows 10 with winpe iso - CDBOOT cannot boot from CD - Code: 5

Tags: windows, ftp, dhcp, syslinux

I am trying to install windows 10 via network boot on a VM (later on, I want to do that on real computers). Therefore I use Debian 9 and VMWare 12.

On my Debian system I have implemented an isc-dhcp-server and a tftpd-hpa-server. On top of that I have syslinux. I changed the menu so that I am able to boot Debian 10 and Kali-Linux via network with images from netboot. This works fine.

Nevertheless, I am not able to boot a windows 10 iso. My file looks as follows:

```
label install
    menu label ^Install
    kernel windows10-installer/amd64/memdisk
    initrd windows10-installer/amd64/win10pe.iso
    append iso raw
```

I created the win10pe.iso from a windows 10 iso by mounting it to a startup script as explaind in this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_PE. Therefore I used the package mkwinpeimg.

When I choose windows 10 to boot, I can see:

```
Loading /memdisk... ok
Loading /winpe10.iso...
```

After one or two minutes the following error message appears:

```
e820: 00000000fffe0000 0000000000020000 2
e820: 0000000100000000 0000000040000000 1
RAMdisk at 0xa833b000, length 0x17ba5000
command line: BOOt_IMAGE=/memdisk iso raw initrd=/win10pe.iso
MEMDISK: IMAGE seems to have fractional end cylinder
MEMDISK: IMAGE appears to be truncated
Disk is hd96, 97189 K, C/H/S = 65535/255/15 (E1 Torito/E1 Torito), EDD on, rw
Using raw access to high memory 
Code 1860, meminfo = 264, cmdline 98, stack 512
Total size needed = 2734 bytes, allocating 3K
Old dos MEMORY at 0x9f000 (map says 0x09f000), loading 0x9e400
1588: 0xfff   15E801:  0x3c00 0xa733
INT 13 08: Success, count = 1, BPT = 0000:0000
Drive probing gives drive shift limit: 0xe1
old: int13 = cd00012b  int15 = f000f895  int1e = f000efc7
new: int13 = 9e40000a  int15 = 9e4003fd  int1e = f000efc7
Loading boot sector... booting...
CDBOOT: Cannot boot from CD - Code: 5
_
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong. Is there a mistake with my winpe or my startup script or is ca. 300MB to much for my ftp server? I have also read something about gpxelinux.0 instead of pxelinux.0, but I do not know where tp get gpxelinux.0. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanche.